# Importing a namespace into the lein repl and refer to it

Tags: clojure

In a file I can do this:

```
(:require [clojurewerkz.neocons.rest :as nr])
```

how can I import this into the repl and still be able to refer to it by 'nr'?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Lee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32783234/124319) is right, of course, but why do you need to quote? The vector `[...]` is evaluated and the values inside too, and here both `clojurewerkz.neocons.rest` and `nr` are treated as variables, which are unbound (you do have an error message, don't you?). You can also choose to quote the symbols:

```
(require ['clojurewerkz.neocons.rest :as 'nr])
```

This also means that you could `require` namespaces dynamically, if you pass a variable.

But then, why don't you need to quote inside a file? I suppose that this is because the `(require ... )` found in your file is enclosed in an `ns` macro, and as such, the forms are not evaluated. See [`require`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/require).

Comment: Thanks for explaining why to quote in this case. I made the same mistake again and again and now my confusion was replaced by understanding :-)

Comment: @ChristianRodemeyer Thanks, you comment is much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `require` and quote the vector:

```
(require '[clojurewerkz.neocons.rest :as nr])
```