# Why do we need ' in (require '[...]]) with Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I see that we don't need ' with `(ns ...)` as ns is a macro.
However, why do we need ' in `(require '[...])`? I thought that Clojure's vector is a fancy way to avoid ', but now I see one here.

We use `(require 'clojure.string)` so `require` seems to be a function, but we don't quote a vector when given as a parameter.

[image]

The error message from not quoting is also confusing.

Comment: Relevant, almost duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32783187/124319

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because `require` is implemented as a function and not a macro, hence it needs a quoted libspec. An unquoted libspec would be evaluated like this:

```
user=> [clojure.set :as s]
CompilerException java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: clojure.set
```

thus yielding an error.

However, `ns` is implemented as a macro and has full control over if or when to evaluate its arguments any further, so you don't need to quote the libspec. You can look at a macroexpansion of ns and see what happens when it is expanded:

```
user=> (use 'clojure.pprint)
nil
user=> (pprint (macroexpand '(ns foo (:require [clojure.set :as s]))))
(do
 (clojure.core/in-ns 'foo)
 (clojure.core/with-loading-context
  (clojure.core/refer 'clojure.core)
  (clojure.core/require '[clojure.set :as s]))
 (if
  (.equals 'foo 'clojure.core)
  nil
  (do
   (clojure.core/dosync
    (clojure.core/commute
     @#'clojure.core/*loaded-libs*
     clojure.core/conj
     'foo))
   nil)))
nil
```

As you can see, `ns` just takes the libspec as it is and quotes it for you before passing it to require, so you don't have to.

Answer (score 5):

The niche is: Quoting a vector is essentially quoting every sub-forms inside the vector form.

```
user> (= '[a b c] ['a 'b 'c])
=> true
```

The `require` form can take either a quoted symbol, referencing a namespace, or it can take a vector of quoted symbols putting further restrictions.